# Where to Learn magento 2 Advance development?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database

I want to take Magento 2 associate exam is there any preferred way that can help me to clear that exam, If yes please provide me your answers on understanding the magento core structure to clear that exam.
I have already reviewed the Magento DevDocs and found it useful sometimes but When comes to complex scenario then Magento Docs seems difficult to do the job and can't help with client's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Book called **Magento 2 developer's guide** that helped me to understand the core functionality of the Magento and there is Also a video course Available by **Packtpublisher**, if you are not very found of reading stuff. You can watch that Video course and you will get good knowledge about all Magento aspects.
To further increase your knowledge you must knows how to override a class and How to do the same Magento Tasks using your custom commands to get Clear understanding of Magento classes.
You must also knows the database Architecture of Magento for various entities.
At last you can go to **Alen Storm's** website when you get intermediate level experience in Magento To get more advance knowledge of Magento Addons tools like **Pestle** to easily build modules with great speed and **Silksoftware website** to generate module, override classes without writting the same code again and again.

But you need to stay up to date with **hands on experience** with Magento issues in every version and their fixes as well, You can go to the **Magento Github repository** and read their forms for that or for latest new features go to **devdocs** for study.

Comment: Thank you @Manish I really appreciate you answer for all those who are craving to become expert in the field of Magento CMS.

Comment: Most Welcome Rohit.

Comment: Does Magento 1 knowledge is still required or helpful in Magento 2 Associate developer exam?

Comment: If you came from previous version of Magento, Which was Magento 1.x.x, some of the Magento features are same while there is enhanced security in Magento 2 and whole code is revised for that, So, There is lot to learn for that.

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Comment: Mage2gen https://mage2gen.com/ hands down is better than pestle and silksoftware website. Although I agree Alan Storm website is a reputable well written source of information